# Serialization of ArrayList in POJO class

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

For a stream processing job, I have defined a POJO class with a generic parameter `T` and a property of type `ArrayList<T>`, which I use as element type in a `DataStream`, as well as the type of state stores in stateful computations in a `CoKeyedProcessFunction`.

```
class TestClass<T> {
    ArrayList<T> list;
    // ... getter and setter for list
}
```

For the `ArrayList<T>`, Flink's serialization falls back to Kryo, about which Flink warns on startup of the stream processing job.

As it seems that Flink contains specialized serializers for Lists, in particular ArrayLists, I would have expected that Flink recognizes and uses these automatically, in the same way as, e.g., primitive values and their boxed versions.

Is there anything I have to do to force Flink to use the right serializer?

Comment: Can You share some code? Generally, it shouldn't be a problem to serialize a list without Kryo.

Comment: It turns out that Flink does not fall back to Kryo if I use `List<T>` as the type of the property. Then, the serialization works independently of the implementation of the list. Deserialization always seems to use the ArrayList implementation.

Comment: Yes, that's the expected behavior and I think it's described in the docs. The `ListSerializer` always uses `ArrayList` as the type.